# ¿Git reconoce la tilde como caracter especial en la configuración?

Tags: git

Hace ya más de año que configuré mi nombre de usuario en git y no lo recordaba y escribí: `git config user.name` para verlo y me apareció: `Roberto MejÃ-­a` como en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda es si el caracter de la tilde es lo que hace que se vea así. En todo caso, ¿dónde podría revisar si aceptan caracteres con tilde? Y en caso de que no acepte tildes, ¿cómo podría hacer para editarlo? y ¿este cambio afectaría mis repositorios remotos futuros y presentes?

Comment: ¿Podrías dar más datos sobre la plataforma con la que trabajas (sistema operativo, terminal, juego de caracteres del terminal, etc)? Yo trabajo con git usando mi nombre y apellidos con signos de acentuación (Óscar García) sin ningún tipo de problemas. Tiene toda la pinta de que estás teniendo problemas con el juego de caracteres de tu sistema operativo.

Comment: Hola, Oscar. No estoy seguro que juego de caracteres especiales tiene mi terminal, pero mi S.O es Windows 10 Pro, y la terminal que estoy usando es Git Bash. Justo estoy intentando buscar alguna plataforma tipo GitHub o el editor de código Visual Studio Code que me muestre si aparece mis datos con la tilde o sin ella, pero no se donde darle clic o en que parte buscar para ver esa información.

Comment: No conozco ese terminal, pero debería tener en sus opciones elegir la configuración local (locale) y el juego de caracteres (charset). Echa un vistazo y configura en UTF-8 el juego de caracteres y, si te lo permite, la configuración local en `es_ES` o, mejor aún, `es_ES@UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0):

La codificación en la que se ha introducido "Roberto Mejía" la primera vez era UTF-8. La configuración de la consola donde estás visualizando esa información ahora no es UTF-8 (si estás en España es posible que sea ISO-8859-1), y ése es el problema.

Seguramente entre la configuración de tu nombre en GIT y la visualización en la consola cambiaste la configuración de la codificación de caracteres por defecto.

Si no es el caso, lo que te puede haber pasado es que editaste el fichero de configuración con un editor y lo guardaste como UTF-8.

**En resumidas:**

1. o bien cambias la codificación de caracteres en la consola a UTF-8 (opción recomendada)
2. o bien cambias el nombre de nuevo con `git config` desde esa misma consola, para que el dato introducido y el consultado sean el mismo

Answer (score -2):

Hoy volví a aplicar `git config user.name` para ver mi nombre de usuario de git y me apareció la tilde, no estoy seguro de qué pasó. Ahora ya sé que git acepta estos caracteres también.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ten cuidado, es muy probable que hayas configurado tu nombre en ISO-8859-15 y que cuando subas tu código a plataformas como GitHub o GitLab (donde suelen usar UTF-8) salgan caracteres extraños en vez de las tildes (el carácter de reemplazo �). Pero, lo peor, es que editarás y verás el código de tu aplicación en un juego de caracteres erróneo si no arreglas la configuración de tu terminal.

Answer (score -3):

Buen día.
Git no reconoce caracteres latinos, esa es la causa de que tu nombre se vea así, si pones una tilde como es el caso este muestra una entidad, te recomiendo no usarlas, espero te sirva.

para cambiar tu nombre de usuario utiliza el siguiente comando:

```
$git config user.name "Roberto Mejia"
```

Comment: Git reconoce "caracteres latinos". Otra cosa es que el terminal del usuario no sepa interpretarlos.

Comment: Exactamente, @OscarGarcia. En git he visto los nombres con caracteres de todo tipo sin problemas.